# Data Validation Batch Edit

Tags: excel, validation

I am trying to create a vocabulary quiz in excel, where a correct answer is the only possible input into a cell. So far, I use data validation to ensure that outcome, but cannot figure out a way to batch edit data validation. I want every blank cell's validation to equal the adjacent cell, which contains the correct answer. I was hoping that copying one correctly formatted cell and pasting it in an empty cell would cause the new cell to reference the new adjacent cell, but have found that the new empty cell still validates according to the old cell.  In other words, I would like the cell's data validation to copy and paste sequentially, like when you drag a cell containing the number 1 and the cells below populate with 1, 2, 3, etc.

This is a problem that has to do with efficiency. I could accomplish what I want by data validating every cell to its adjacent "by hand," but it takes a very long time with large amounts of data. I've tried conditional formatting as well--a correct answer turns the cell green--but have run into the same problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: So if the "correct" answers are in column **C**, you want the DV for **B1** to be the value in **C1** and the DV for **B2** to be the value in **C2**, etc. ??

Comment: I suggest to start you should Record Macro with "Use Relative References" enabled of you adding validation to a cell and setting the validation source as the cell next to it. Then you can adapt your recorded code by adding a loop that goes through your determined range. Once you have some sample code feel free to add to your post if you get stuck anywhere. Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: Ok, that's a tough one. I'm going to try to learn how to loop a range. It seems like every time I want to perform this operation, I'll have to edit the macro with the new range. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how you did the copy/paste, but it should work fine.  Here is an example.

Set up the initial data validation.  I am using the `List` version of it with a single cell reference.  Note that the single cell reference is defined relatively (no dollar signs in it).  I removed the `In-cell dropdown` option so the answer isn't visible!

[image: set up initial data validation]

Now if I copy that cell and paste one cell below, it will apply the data validation with the range updated.  I did this with a simple copy of `C6` and paste into `C7`.  I changed the value to `b` after the paste to not get the error.  When I open the validation for `C7` I see the new range (`D7`).

[image: copy/paste result]

You can paste to a larger range than 1 cell and it will update all of the references accordingly.

Comment: It was the dollar signs. Thanks so much. Problem solved, and it saves me so much time. Have a good one.